# Error in creating new angular 4 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed angular cli successfully but when i run this command "ng new myApp" it give an error

"ng is not recognized as an internal or external command"
and when i run this command ""

```
+-- @angular/cli@1.4.1
+-- angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
+-- babel-core@6.25.0
+-- cordova@6.5.0
+-- ionic@2.2.3
+-- lite-server@2.3.0
+-- live-server@1.2.0
+-- nodemon@1.11.0
+-- npm@5.4.1
`-- udemy-dl@0.0.9
```

Errors are given below

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^5.0.1, required by @angular/core@2.4.10
npm ERR! missing: q@^1.4.1, required by cordova-common@2.0.0
npm ERR! missing: underscore@^1.8.3, required by cordova-common@2.0.0
npm ERR! missing: base64-js@^1.0.2, required by buffer@4.9.1
npm ERR! missing: isarray@^1.0.0, required by buffer@4.9.1
npm ERR! missing: acorn@^4.0.3, required by syntax-error@1.3.0
npm ERR! missing: punycode@1.3.2, required by url@0.11.0
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.1, required by util@0.10.3
npm ERR! missing: debug@2.6.4, required by finalhandler@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: debug@2.6.1, required by send@0.15.1
npm ERR! missing: ms@0.7.2, required by send@0.15.1
npm ERR! missing: glob@^7.1.1, required by init-package-json@1.10.1
npm ERR! missing: glob@^7.1.1, required by read-package-json@2.0.5
npm ERR! missing: abbrev@~1.0.9, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: ansicolors@~0.3.2, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: ansistyles@~0.1.3, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: archy@~1.0.0, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: async-some@~1.0.2, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: char-spinner@~1.0.1, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: chmodr@~1.0.2, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: chownr@~1.0.1, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: cmd-shim@~2.0.2, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: columnify@~1.5.4, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: config-chain@~1.1.10, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: dezalgo@~1.0.3, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: editor@~1.0.0, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: fs-vacuum@~1.2.9, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: fs-write-stream-atomic@~1.0.8, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: fstream-npm@~1.1.1, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: github-url-from-git@~1.4.0, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: github-url-from-username-repo@~1.0.2, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: glob@~7.0.6, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: hosted-git-info@~2.1.5, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: init-package-json@~1.9.4, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: lockfile@~1.0.1, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: lru-cache@~4.0.1, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: node-gyp@~3.6.0, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: nopt@~3.0.6, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: normalize-git-url@~3.0.2, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: npm-cache-filename@~1.0.2, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: npm-install-checks@~1.0.7, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: npm-package-arg@~4.1.0, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: npm-registry-client@~7.2.1, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: npm-user-validate@~0.1.5, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: npmlog@~2.0.4, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: path-is-inside@~1.0.0, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: read-installed@~4.0.3, required by npm@2.15.12
npm ERR! missing: readable-stream@~2.1.5, required by npm@2.15.12
```

How can I solve it? What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install Angular Client globally in orders to invoke ng command directly, please run:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 2):

Update or install angular cli package with the following command:

```
c:\ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After that create a new project on your desired location by the following command:

```
c:\ npm new projectName
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem starts with node installation .
Please check the node versions by using

```
node -v
npm -v
```

node must be latest version as `v8.5.0` and npm must be the latest version as `5.4.1`

then please reinstall angular cli by using

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

then check the versions

```
ng -v
```

version will be 1.4.1 and if everything is ok you can create the project as

```
ng new myNewProject
```

Comment: Angular CLI requirement for Node 6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher.

Comment: my current node version is v6.10.0 how can i update node?

Comment: By using nvm or downloading latest version from the site https://nodejs.org/en/. I dont know your OS but there ise a installationg guide in the site.

Comment: U are wellcome :)